# WooCommerce Single Product Page Seperate Cost

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a second button to a product page with a updated price.

For example I'm using [add_to_cart id='$product->id'] which displays correctly, but I would like to assign this short code a custom price.

The results should show two buttons on a single product page. One with the regular price value and the other with the custom price value.

I tried doing this through variables, but need them in two buttons instead of a drop down.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would the same product have different costs? And variable sounds right to me... then you'd just need to write a shortcode for displaying a variation (assuming `[add_to_cart="$variation_id"]` doesn't work.

Comment: The same product would have two different prices because it will be labeled as a trial product which one can also purchase. So for example if I want to try the product I would select the button that's prices at 0.00, but if I want to buy the product I would click on the button which contains the regular price. So instead on created two products I would like to create 1 product with two different prices. One will be the regular price and the other set to free. I tried using variables which displays correctly, but I need them in a form of a separate buttons.

Comment: [Source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.14/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php#L451) suggests that the `[add_to_cart]` shortcode supports variations, so, my advice is to keep it as a variable product and use `[add_to_cart="$variation_id"]`.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thank you for that hint. That actually worked. Now i just have to customizing a couple of things to get it how I want it. I appreciate the help!